# Virtual bridge/switch for Windows server&client?

Tags: vpn, switch, bridge

I can't find a very simple application, with litle to zero configuration on both client and server side which would help one computer to bring other computers on an existing private LAN.

OpenVPN seems like an overkill for this type of thing, and is really hard to get running or debug by various clueless people trying to connect.

Does such a software exist? It's very odd not to.

The Windows provided VPN (PPTP over TCP and GRE) is not what I'm looking for because it is often filtered by ISPs.

Only TCP and UDP solutions pls. Encryption is not needed.

Edit: This question is getting a lot of hate. I just asked if a network bridge software, which configures itself with 2 clicks on a client side without any sort of admin intervention or help, exists. I will never ask another question on serverfault or even answer one. Sorry, but I was better off configuring ovpn and reading error logs than fighting non constructive comments.

Comment: Generally we consider questions asking for product suggestions off-topic here.  The fact that you seem to be unwilling to put some effort into learning how to configure the OSS OpenVPN server/client makes me believe that you are not asking this question as a professional system administrator.  Why do you think you need a **bridge**, and no a routed VPN?  What are you doing, that doesn't work directly over the Internet?

Comment: @Zoredache I didn't say I don't want to learn. I said OpenVPN is overkill for the simplest thing. Also you are assuming and implying and and are also saying I don't want to learn. You are wrong. I already know how to configure it. Connecting clients don't. I have listed specific needs and this is turning into **OpenVPN fanboism** (every commenter and answer are blindly, and forcefully against my mentioning it as ruled out, offerring it as a solution).

Comment: @Zoredache "What are you doing, that doesn't work directly over the Internet?" Now you are off-topic. Seriously, your question implies doubt over my need of a VPN. You are assuming way too much, see my previous comment too. I don't know how you got upvoted (and since you like throwing assumptions at me: I bet you got upvoted by your friends).

Comment: `Seriously, your question implies doubt over my need of a VPN`, no I simply doubt your ability to ask a decent question describing your requirements.  I have some level of doubt about if you need this VPN for some kind of professional network setup, or if you are looking for some kind network for people to play LAN games on.

Comment: I specifically asked about your requirement for a bridge (layer 2), because if you drop that requirement or provide more detail, I might be able to make some alternate suggestions.  Instead of reading my comment and adding the additional information I asked for you have decided to attack me.  You are far more likely to get help if you ignore any perceived fanboism, or insults, and skip directly to the part of the comment asking you for more information.

Comment: If you don't like people suggesting OpenVPN, then you should provide a lot more detail then simply saying it is overkill, difficult, or expensive.  These adjectives do not provide us enough useful detail about why it is over kill, or too difficult.

Comment: @zoredache I was merely defending from your numerous offending  assumptions directed at me. `no I simply doubt your ability to ask a decent question describing your requirements` I doubt your ability to answer it without saying "OpenVPN". I have provided more than enough detail in my question. What I will be using this for (including games with no internet support, 3DS Max Backburner which misteriously crashes when over the internet, remoting into to LAN network services such as Windows shares blocked by all ISPs I know of (I do this often), etc.) is really not helping for a solution.

Comment: @zoredache If I want to play games or turn my home computer into a work horse for some friend, I'd have to configure OpenVPN for them, ask them for logs with errors, etc. I have been through this too many times. If my question doesn't have an answer, that's fine.

Comment: If this is for games and personal stuff, then take a look at Hamachi.  https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/  Keep in mind that this is NOT bridged, but it does give you an un-firewalled network between the various nodes.

Comment: @Zoredache I know about Hamachi, Tunngle, Garena, etc. This isn't about games specifically. Also, my question is quite clear about turning a computer into a server, not using some 3rd party VPN server solution.

Answer (score 3):

Layer 2 VPN that's bridgeable? Sorry, but i'd go with OpenVPN.

With one-on-one connection, you can go with static keys to avoid creating a CA, and use it over any port you wish. If you need to use it in extremely firewalled networks, you can run it over tcp/443, which usually passes 99% of firewalls as https (ssl) traffic.

Comment: I tried the OpenVPN vmware appliance for this, yet its asking me to buy 10 licenses, yearly. I really don't want to maintain and debug configurability issues with connecting clients, so I'm not going to configure an OpenVPN server. I am looking for something simpler.

Comment: you dont need an apliance, you jsut need the OpenVPN package (check under community downloads)

Comment: The appliance had a nice web page with preconfigured .ovpn configs for clients. Other than that, read my previous comment again, I've edited it.

Comment: OpenVPN windows GUI client is installed with a few clicks. Client config file is simple (documented) and the same for all clients if you use the same names for the files. After that, you only need to copy the certificates and the config file to the right place... a 2 or 3 lines script can do that for the client and you won't need to debug after the 1st time if you do it right. Anyways, you won't find a software to open (and protect) your LAN to the Internet without configuring some things... and if you find one, there is a fair chance you get uninvited people on your LAN quickly...